# Disable Antivirus with command prompt

Tags: windows-10, prompt

I have the latest version of Avast as anti virus ; without using its interface , how can I disable it with the command prompt ? I have Windows 10 .

Comment: If this would have been so easy wouldn't every virus do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Launch `services.msc` from a *Run* box or the *Command Prompt* to start Services, then
- Find the service you want to stop.
- Right-click on it, select Properties and note the "Service name" field. The "Path to executable:" field includes the name of the process.

(It might be a name like `"avast! Antivirus"`.)

- Then use `net stop "avast! Antivirus"` on cmd

Comment: You can type `net start` to find a list. No need to use the GUI.

Comment: @LPChip yep, you are right. Slipped my mind

Comment: Did someone test this?